# azure python web app on linux custom deploy.sh won't create python virtual env

Tags: python, linux, azure, web-applications

I'm creating python web app on Linux in Azure cloud using zip deploy method, deployment done by custom deploy.sh, when the zip package upload deploy.sh run by automatically and it wan't create the virtual env that mentioned in the deploy.sh and the required dependency as well,but when i run that manually by ssh it works fine. can anybody have any clue about this.
custom deploy.sh commands as follows,

```
export PIP3="pip3"
  export ANTENV="antenv3.6"
  export PYTHON3="/usr/local/bin/python3"

  echo "Found requirements.txt"
  echo "Python Virtual Environment: $ANTENV"
  echo "Python Version: $PYTHON3"

  #2a. Setup virtual Environment
  echo "Create virtual environment"
  $PYTHON3 -m venv $ANTENV --copies

  #2b. Activate virtual environment
  echo "Activate virtual environment"
  . $ANTENV/bin/activate

  #2c. Install dependencies
  #sleep 120

  #2d. Install dependencies
  echo "Installing libraries specified in requirements.txt"
  $PIP3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the command `source path/bin/activate` to start the virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,
 already tried that one but not worked...

Comment: Do you create the zip package in Windows?

Comment: nope, it created on Linux